# Different strings in MySQL between localhost and production

Tags: php, mysql, database, cakephp, cakephp-2.5

I would need your help on this one because I can't find the solution myself:

I have a project built on cakephp ver 2.5.1.
I'm entering data into my database on localhost (MAMP on my macbook; VARCHAR 255 utf8_bin - string being saved: HP) and all strings saved on my localhost appear in numbers (string HP is being saved as 4850).

The funny thing is if I copy that same database and import it on my production server all the strings are correct, HP is HP and not 4850... so I'm guessing I just misconfigured something on localhost...

Any help on the matter will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How are you viewing the string? It might be that your software is converting it.

Comment: In ascii, "HP" is 48 hex 50 hex. Perhaps a character encoding issue.

Comment: I'm viewing it through phpmyadmin in safari.

Comment: Try this: in phpmyadmin table display page, click on the '+ Options' link and uncheck  "Show binary contents as HEX"

Comment: I write it down as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: in phpmyadmin table display page, click on the '+ Options' link and uncheck "Show binary contents as HEX"

Answer (score 0):

Check what the column type is in your local host. I'm thinking that you might have created the column as an integer instead of a varchar or text.

Comment: as written in my post, column is varchar(255) collation: utf8_bin. @Cameron